# How to use injectRepository in e2e test in nest js

Tags: nestjs, repository, nest, e2e

I have service where I use repository like this in constructor
 `@InjectRepository(MyRepo, 'dataSource') private myRepo: MyRepo`

and everything works well, but when I try to access myRepo in e2e test

`myRepo = moduleRef.get<MyRepo>(MyRepo);`

`const result = myRepo.find();` I got error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository')

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: I think no, because I do not want to mock. I want use real repository